# Вопрос по шифратору, как шифровать не один символ а два?

Tags: delphi

```
var
   s,v:string;
   n,i,j,k:integer;
begin
   memo2.Clear;
   k:=memo1.Lines.Count-1;
   for j:=0 to k do begin
      s:='';
      s:=memo1.Lines[j];
      n:=length(s);
      For i:=0 to n do begin
         if s<>'' then
         case s[i] of
         'а': insert('%',v,i);
         и т.д.
```

т.е. не 'а' в '%' а 'а' в '%='. Соответственно тот же вопрос и по дешифратору

```
var
   s,v:string;
   n,i,j,k:integer;
begin
   memo2.Clear;
   k:=memo1.Lines.Count-1;
   for j:=0 to k do begin
      s:='';
      s:=memo1.Lines[j];
      n:=length(s);
      For i:=0 to n do begin
         if s<>'' then
         case s[i] of
        '%': insert('а',v,i);
        и т.д.
```

шифратор стал выдавать `'%='` (как мне нужно) после добавления `v:='';`
а на счет дешифратора не имею представления что сделать, при вставке второго символа сюда `'%=': insert('а',v,i);` выдает ошибку `incompatible types 'char' and 'string'`

помогите пожалуйста с решением данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я бы попробовал так:

```
var s:string;
j:integer;
begin
memo2.Clear;
k:=memo1.Lines.Count-1;
for j:=0 to k do
begin
s:='';
s:=memo1.Lines[j];
s:=StringReplace(s, '%=', 'а', [rfReplaceAll]); {заменит во всей строке s символы '%=' на 'а'}
//    и так далее, допустим заменить "(((" на "b"
s:=StringReplace(s, '(((', 'b',[rfReplaceAll]);
...
```

Comment: попробовал, хм.. ничего не происходит

Comment: А нет, все, заработало. Добавил `memo2.Lines.Add(s);`. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!)